# Winrt Tablet app unable to install, Access Denied error

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, package

I am getting this error while installing my winrt tablet app in my tablet. I have refreshed my windows and after refreshing all build that I make from my computer shows this error on my tablet.

Add-AppxPackage : Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x80070005, Access is denied.

error 0x80070005: Creating file \?\C:\Program
Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.VCLibs.110.00_11.0.51106.1_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\AppxManifest.xml failed.

NOTE: For additional information, look for [ActivityId] aad50c12-16c7-0001-df14-d5aac716d101 in the Event Log or use
the command line Get-AppxLog -ActivityID aad50c12-16c7-0001-df14-d5aac716d101

At C:\Users\Advansoft_Surface\Desktop\app 41115\UniversalApp.Salik.Windows_1.0.0.117_Test\Add-AppDevPackage.ps1:388
char:13
+             Add-AppxPackage -Path $DeveloperPackagePath.FullName -DependencyPath ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (C:\Users\Advans..._x64.appxbundle:String) [Add-AppxPackage], PSSecurityE
   xception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DeploymentError,Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.AddAppxPackageCommand

Error: Could not install the app.

Comment: Is it sideloaded? Are do you have a developer license? Did you enable "Allow all trusted apps to install" in your Local Group Policy?

Comment: I should do this in my tablet or in my development pc?

Comment: There is something very strange. All the build that I have made before are still able to install on my tablet. Which shows tablet setting is ok

Comment: And new builds are not installing on my tablet but wroking on client's tablet and on my all windows8.1 pc

Comment: For apps which are not in the store you need a sideloading key. On which OS are you trying to install?

Comment: how can I get side loading key? I am trying on windows 8.1 x64

Comment: http://blogs.windows.com/itpro/2014/04/03/windows-8-1-update-sideloading-enhancements/